# mysql Database logic advise on zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-design

I have employee table and training table, I want employees to login and see only training suggested his/her departments.
is this good approach, separate suggested departments with comma ?
and query will be select from training table where employee department like suggested department ?

```
epmloyeetable       
id   Name     Department
1    John      Finance
2    Michael   Logistics

training table      
id  name      suggested_department
1   php       IT, Finance
2   vba       IT, Logistics
3   java      Logistics, Finance
```

Second question is should I use numbers instead of department names and create department table? This time i will have to connect more than 2 tables together will this be problem while I will use zend framework

```
epmloyeetable       
id   Name     Department
1    John      Finance
2    Michael   Logistics

training table      
id  name      suggested_department
1   php       1, 2
2   vba       1, 3
3   java      3, 2

departmenttable     
id   Name 
1    IT 
2    Finance
3    Logistic
```

This time query will be select from training table where employee department +',' = suggested department ? 
because there will be 1 and 11 in department id so should i use + 'comma' while selecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second suggestion is better than the first, but in general storing CSV data into a SQL table is sub-optimal for many reasons.  I propose the following design, with the `employeetable` and `departmenttable` tables remaining the same:

```
training table      
id  name      suggested_department
1   php       1
1   php       2
2   vba       1
2   vba       3
3   java      3
3   java      2
```

This alternative to what you have leaving the `training` table *normalized*.  As mentioned, storing CSV data is not ideal, with one example being what if you just wanted to do a simple query asking which training has IT as a suggested department.  With CSV data, you would have to dig through the CSV to find the answer, whereas with my suggested table you can do a simple join, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM training
WHERE suggested_department = 1;
```

Using a normalized table makes it easy to join to other tables, and also allows for the possible use of indices which can make everyday queries much faster.

Comment: Tim Thank you for response. I forgot to write details. I training can be suggested for Department + Function + name. For example PHP training suggested department "IT, Finance", suggested person "Carla" suggested Function "Manager, employee"  ıdea is when IT person at employee or manager level login to system can select "PHP" training. Or Carla from Logistic department even this training not suggested to her department she will see training because suggested to her name. In your case I have to create multi lines for per training x suggested dep x sugg. name x suggested func , am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your other tables look like `training` then you should normalize them too.

Comment: in this case I have to change my create form and edit form functions. For example if you select 2 department script must create 2 different row. And If you want to edit it will be much more complicated too.

Comment: You tagged your question with database design and I have answered.  If your UI requires some changes to support good database design, I'd recommend that you consider making them.